# The $y(\frac{∂z}{∂x})-x(\frac{∂z}{∂y})=0$ equation

Tags: calculus

The   $y(\frac{∂z}{∂x})-x(\frac{∂z}{∂y})=0$   equation,

$u=x$

$v=x^2+y^2$

Write according to the new u, v variables given.

I don't know the question at all. Can you please help for solution?

Comment: Use chain rule to express thr partial derivatives in terms of u and v, and then use the expressions given to eliminate x and y

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I tried, but I couldn't apply the chain rule. Do you have a chance to show only that part?

Comment: Sorry, am on mobile... Maybe someone else will pop by and do it in a bit, otherwise I'll type it up as soon as I'm able to :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am waiting for the solution when you are available :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $z=z(x, y)=z(x(u,v),y(u,v))$ can be obtained system
$$z_{u}^{'} = z_{x}^{'}x_{u}^{'}+z_{y}^{'}y_{u}^{'}$$
$$z_{v}^{'} = z_{x}^{'}x_{v}^{'}+z_{y}^{'}y_{v}^{'}$$
Knowing formulas for $x$ and $y$ you can solve from system $z_{x}^{'}$ and $z_{y}^{'}$

So
$$z_{x}^{'} = \dfrac{z_{u}^{'}y_{v}^{'} - z_{v}^{'}y_{u}^{'}}{x_{u}^{'}y_{v}^{'} - x_{v}^{'}y_{u}^{'}}$$
$$z_{y}^{'} = \dfrac{x_{u}^{'}z_{v}^{'} - x_{v}^{'}z_{u}^{'}}{x_{u}^{'}y_{v}^{'} - x_{v}^{'}y_{u}^{'}}$$

Then we can obtain

$$z_{x}^{'} =z_{u}^{'} +2u z_{v}^{'}$$
$$z_{y}^{'}=2y z_{v}^{'}$$

Finally your equation become
$$yz_{u}^{'}+2u(1-y)z_{v}^{'}$$
where $y$ is from system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting as answer, glad, that it is useful, but it still have 0 estimation - may be you forgot it?.

Comment: I never thought about that part. How will it be?

Comment: Voting is up to you.

Comment: Do you have a chance to send the solution of the problem fully?

Comment: Added solution for system .

Comment: So I'll ask one last thing. Should only u and v be the answer to the question? There are also dz statements in my answer. Can you find the final result?

Comment: You should solve $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$, find their derivatives and then join everything together in initial equation.

Comment: I know I want a lot, but can you solve the last answer? It doesn't matter if you want, thank you anyway.

Comment: Ended, I leave $y$ for you.

Comment: The answer says $dz/du$ in a source. But with your solution, I find the answer $y.dz/du $. Which one is right?

Comment: What is "$y.dz/du$" and how you find it? And, also, it will be good if you share your source.

Comment: There is one source of calculus 2. I found it in this question, but it only writes the answer. It writes  $z_{u}^{'}$  in reply. I find $yz_{u}^{'}$ with your solution.

Comment: It's important what exactly writes your source: what is condition of task, what is question, what you had done etc. Any inexactness results in difference. And, please, do not copy/paste source - if you want to clear situation, share it whole.